# Talend component tPivotToColumnsDelimited generates error "The method parseObject(String) is undefined for the type Object"

Tags: talend

I am using the component `tPivotToColumnsDelimited` in Talend 6.1.1. When I try to run the job I get the error message "The method parseObject(String) is undefined for the type Object".

[image: Talend process map]

In code view I can see the error relates to this line of Talend-generated code:
`sumtPivotToColumnsDelimited_1 = Object.parseObject(row3.Amount + "")`

As you can see from the process flow above, the data comes from an SQL query. The schema flowing into the `tPivotToColumnsDelimited` looks like this:

[image: Talend schema]

The `tPivotToColumnsDelimited` component settings look like this:

[image: tPivotToColumnsDelimited settings]

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: Kindly provide some screenshot of your job design and more details.

Comment: That's Because you put a type String in the agreggate function "sum" you need to put an int for example. What do you want to do exactly can we have more precision like sreen or something like that. Thanks

Comment: I've added more to the description now. The sum function is defined on a dollar value with MS SQL data type VARBINARY.

Comment: Aaah, so now I see the problem. Talend guessed the VARBINARY data type and turns that into an `Object`, when actually it should be treated as a `double`. When I adjust the schema the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Its clear that Talend cannot parse an Object typed variable, You need to change the type of column Ammount to other type like int, float.

[image]

Comment: That code is generater by Talend, and not editable AFAIK.

Comment: Ah, now its clear with the screenshots, updated answer !